# Using Wp_deregister Jquery disable featured image uploader in WordPress?

Tags: jquery

Can someone tell me why (and how to correct this) using `wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' )` in functions.php disables the image uploader in admin.

I'm using wp_register_script to load a lot of scripts for my theme, and if I don't deregister jQuery, my theme is having problems...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a good reason to not want to use jQuery on the front end of your site, you can cause it to only be deregistered on the front end and not in the admin by wrapping your call to `wp_deregister_script()`:

```
// Only deregister jQuery if it is not the admin section
if (!is_admin()){
     wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that by deregistering jQuery in your theme you'll deregister it also in all the WordPress code (admin panel included).

Why can't you use jQuery in your theme? Have you tried to activate the [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) in jQuery???

Comment: In fact I think it has something to do with a noConflict or something. I need jQuery both in Console and Theme, but since I've moved my scripts call in the functions.php, I run into this problem...